# while doing sql I got this error, invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

can someone please help me in this, I am getting the error

> Column 'MoldInfo.SetID' is invalid in the select list because it is
> not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

when I used this query

```
select *
from MoldInfo
group by MoldName
having count(distinct SetID) > 1
```

I want to have an output table with all the columns but some MoldName have repeated entries, I only want the mold name with latest date.

[This is the image of the table 'MoldInfo'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQBwR.png)

Comment: The error message says it all. You typically GROUP BY all columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Quick hint for future reference!  Delete that image.  Then go to workbench, right click on the table name, copy to clipboard, and `Create Statement` -- Paste that here ...  That will allow peeps to recreate the table in their individual environments (reproducible) to better assist you :) -- Or find the equivalency of grabbing a Create Statement from DataGrip or whatever platform you're using.

Comment: Please elaborate @Jarlh

Comment: Thank you @Zak , I'll keep this in mind for future.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you really using? That image looks like SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), which (as its name suggests) is for SQL Server.  Though as you have also been told: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Yes @Larnu you are correct, I am using SSMS.

Comment: Then why have you tagged [[tag:MySQL]]?

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` is meant to be used with aggregate functions and the purpose of it is to define the set of rows that the aggregate function is applied to. Using it with `SELECT *` makes no sense and will result into an error.

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
select MoldName, count(distinct SetID)
from MoldInfo
group by MoldName
having count(distinct SetID) > 1
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is ok to use when you’re running queries interactively and exploring your data. It’s rarely a good choice in code and usually indicates the developer isn’t thinking.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, what I meant that `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` does not make sense.

Comment: If there are same MoldName in the data, I only want the MoldName with latest date

Comment: @MrSingh You should add sample data and expected result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses.  I have been able to resolve the problem myself though.

```
    select distinct a.SetID, a.MoldName, a.StartDate from MoldInfo a
    where a.StartDate = (Select Max(StartDate) from MoldInfo c 
    where c.MoldName = a.MoldName) AND a.MoldName<>''
    order by a.MoldName
```

I am getting the desired output with distinct MoldName with lastest StartDate.

| SetID | MoldName | StartDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 422 | 2-6117:Cap Lid-8 Cavity | 2002-09-05 |
| 433 | 3-6639:Flip Bar-16 Cavity | 2002-12-30 |

If you want all the columns

```
select distinct a.* from MoldInfo a
where a.StartDate = (Select Max(StartDate) from MoldInfo c 
where c.MoldName = a.MoldName) AND a.MoldName<>''
order by a.MoldName
```